# What should I do with geraniums during the winter?

Tags: overwintering, plant-care, geraniums

I brought my geraniums indoors for the winter.

- Do they need light?
- Should I water them?
- Should I cut them? If so, how short?
- When is the best time to take cuttings (i.e. during winter, start of spring, etc.)?

Answer (score 4):

There  are several options. The first is the most common in my area.

From [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=how%20should%20geraniums%20be%20overwintered?&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://www.ipm.iastate.edu/ipm/hortnews/2004/9-17-2004/geraniums.html&ei=jX9qT5jXD6PL0QG5-fHdBg&usg=AFQjCNGOpRDz7rcGb50R5FwPKAimVFqhkg), Dig them up before frost, remove the soil, and put them in open paper bags. Then hang them from the rafters in a dry cool (45-50 degrees Fahrenheit) room. Several times during the winter, take them down, soak them in water for a couple hours, and return them to their original location.

Another option is to pot them and grow them through the winter like a houseplant, and move them out to the garden after it warms up in spring.

The last one I will mention is to cut all the stems off at ground level and leave the roots. Insert each stem into a tin can of soil. Keep the plants in a bright but cool location until spring, when they are rooted.

Comment: I tried the paper bag method and it did not work for me as I do not have an area in the house that is 45-50 degrees Fahrenheit.  Cool temperatures are essential to success.

Answer (score 4):

I pot them and put them in a sunny windowsill or under my grow lights. Either way they're not very happy, and they lose a lot of leaves, but they also give me cheery red flowers all winter, and stay alive until I can put them back out in the spring. Under the grow lights, they get really long-stemmed, and I generally cut off a lot of that growth when I put them back out. I'm pretty aggressive about deadheading and pulling off dead leaves, because they're indoors and I have to look at them.